# Custom app activities

Tags: activities-overview

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

When I hit the `super` key `Activities` is called and I can see all the windows.

My question: Is there a way to customize a shortcut so that if I hit (for example) `super`+`t` I see all the windows of a particular app (for example the **terminal**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, although that would be very useful. In the current versions of Gnome Shell, the overview shows all active windows. There is no way to show windows of a single application only (likely with the exception, of course, of dedicated Gnome Shell extensions, but none exists that does that a.f.a.i.k).

For sure, that would be a very valid feature request for Gnome Shell. The forthcoming Ubuntu 22.20, however, will feature app spread in the Ubuntu dock, i.e., where clicking the dock will show a spread of the windows of the current applications only.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with [dash-to-dock extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) because of this PR: https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/pull/1253